# Кнопка уезжает вниз

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтобы кнопка не уезжала вниз?

```css
.header {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.logo {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.button {
  float: right;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 1s;
  height: 32px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="header">
  <h3><a href="http://olx2.ua/" class="logo col-xl-1">Olx2</a></h3>
  <form action="/add-product.php">
    <input type="submit" class="button col-xl-2" value="Подать объявление">
  </form>
  <hr>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header {
  padding-top: 10px;
display: block;
overflow:auto;

}

.logo {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.button {
  float: right;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 1s;
  height: 32px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
}
div {
 white-space: nowrap;
display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="header">
  <div>
  <h3><a href="http://olx2.ua/" class="logo col-xl-1">Olx2</a></h3>
  </div>
<div>
  <form action="/add-product.php">
    <input type="submit" class="button col-xl-2" value="Подать объявление">
  </form>
</div>
  <hr>
</div>
```